# Should I download Qt for Android (5.5) when I already have Qt for windows 32(MinGW)?

Tags: android, windows, qt, mobile, mingw

[www.qt.io/download-open-source/](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/)

Under offline installers for windows, I have already downloaded and used Qt 5.5 for win32 (MinGW). I want to start developing android apps.

So can I just install some extras or do I have to download the 1GB Qt 5.5 for Android too?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary.

Open your Qt Maintenance Tool and expand the version Qt 5.5. You will see some checkboxes where you can select the Android compilers or packages and update your Qt framework.

After that, remember that you need to [configure](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html) Qt Creator in order to have the necessary Android kits which will be used in your projects.